ASP.NET Core Web API : authorization using Identity Framework
I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project where I want to allow users to log in using user/password, and also Google, Facebook, and Apple. When using external services to log in, a user should be created which will be used to track their activity in the application: assign points, let them redeem for gifts and other features.
Currently, the solution I have involves:

Validating the tokens received from external services
Manually generating JWT Bearer tokens

But this approach has a lot of disadvantages and doesn't use much of what the Identity Framework offers. Example of the controller getting the user from the authorization code in Google:
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] GoogleLoginRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _googleAuthService.GetUserDetails(request.IdToken);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest("Invalid user information received from Google services");
    
        user = await _createUser.ExecuteAsync(user);

        if (user == null)
            return Problem("Unable to create user");
        
        var tokenResponse = await _userTokenService.GenerateAccessToken(user);

        return Ok(tokenResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem("Internal server error");
    }
}

As you can see, the generation of the bearer is manual using the UserTokenService:
public async Task<AccessTokenResponse> GenerateAccessToken(IdentityUser user)
{
    var userRoles = await _context.UserRoles
        .Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.Id)
        .Join(_context.Roles, ur => ur.RoleId, r => r.Id, (ur, r) => r.Name)
        .ToListAsync();

    var roleClaims = userRoles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)).ToList();

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.NormalizedUserName!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email!)
    }
    .Union(roleClaims);

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(int.Parse(_configuration["Jwt:ExpirationInHours"]!));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: expiration,
        signingCredentials: creds);

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    var refreshToken = await GenerateRefreshTokenAsync(user);

    return new AccessTokenResponse
    {
        AccessToken = jwt,
        ExpiresIn = (int)(expiration - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds,
        RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token
    };
}

I would like to know how to properly do this flow using SignInManager, UserManager etc., so that the user can receive their new bearer token managed by Identity Framework. Any guidance, tutorials or docs are really appreciated.

this, maybe ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

After getting google login details you may try to get the user by email from your saved identities, and use the method SignInManager.SignInAsync to sign in the user directly without any other credentials
